# What is the reason for fatal error: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop

Tags: makefile

The error occurs when I tried to run the command `make install` under Ubuntu 16.04 that

`*** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.`

I have already run `make` command with several errors `fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'`, which didn't lead to halting the command. I have no idea whether these errors matter.

My makefile is:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    make -C $@

install:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        make -C $$dir install; \
    done

.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS)
```

Specifically, I want to know how the makefile works after `install:`.

The project should install an APP on the connected phone Nexus 5. But actually, there's no such APP on my phone.

Comment: Probably some of your subdirs do not contain any Makefile. Anyway, this is not an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your Makefile is properly formatted, with tabs where they should be, etc.

Then, when you run `make install` in the top level directory, your `Makefile` does have a rule to make the target `install:` it says to loop on your subdirectories, enter each one of them, and run `make install` there (this is what the `-C` option does). One of those sub-makes fails, most probably because, in its respective subdirectory, it doesn’t find a `Makefile` with an `install` recipe in it. When the sub-make fails, the loop goes on with the remaining sub-makes (unless the shell was instructed otherwise by means of the `-e` switch), and the final return code of the whole recipe will be the return code of the last sub-make.

There are some points worth discussing in your `Makefile` (for example, `install` should be listed as a `.PHONY` target), but you don’t provide enough information to clarify them: for example, is it really necessary to have the shell loop through the subdirectories in a particular order? Usually, a better policy is to have `make` parallelize the sub-makes whenever possible (and, as a side effect, have `make` stop when the first submake fails...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind reply, Dario. So I'm still wondering whether the mistake you mentioned in your second paragraph that target `install:` is missing will halt the `make install` progress, or will the progress just skip them and compile it successfully?